# How to make a jQuery filter that filter on class names (multiple) dropdown

Tags: jquery

How can you filter by multiple classnames in a li.
I want if you select from dropdown that the values checked if they are in li as classnames.

```
    <select name="hospital-list" id="hospital-list">
        <option value="doctor-item" selected="selected">Selectziekenhuis</option>
       <option value="doctor-item-option1" >optoin 1</option>
 <option value="doctor-item-option1" >optoin 2</option>
    </select>



    <select name="function-list" id="function-list">
        <option selected="selected">Select functie</option>
    <option value="function-option1" >function 1</option>
 <option value="function-option2" >function 2</option>
    </select>

    $('select').click(function(){

    // filterSelect();

    console.log('filter aangeroepen');
    $(this).change(function() {
    var optionValue1 = $('select #hospital-list').attr("value");
    var optionValue2 = $('select #function-list').attr("value");
    console.log(optionValue1);
    console.log(optionValue2);
    $(".doctor-item").not("." + optionValue1 + "." + optionValue2).hide();
    });
```

Example:

```
 <li class=" doctor-item-option1 function-option2 doctor-item">
```

Comment: Did you tried below answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get value of select using `.val()` then pass that value i.e :  `$("." + optionValue1 + "." + optionValue2).show()` to show li where both classes are there else hide them.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("select").change(function() {
  $(".doctor-item").hide(); //hide all
  var optionValue1 = $('select#hospital-list').val();
  var optionValue2 = $('select#function-list').val();
  $("." + optionValue1 + "." + optionValue2).show() //show only when same
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="hospital-list" id="hospital-list">
  <option value="doctor-item" selected="selected">Selectziekenhuis</option>
  <option value="doctor-item-option1">optoin 1</option>
  <option value="doctor-item-option2">optoin 2</option>
</select>
<select name="function-list" id="function-list">
  <option selected="selected">Select functie</option>
  <option value="function-option1">function 1</option>
  <option value="function-option2">function 2</option>
</select>

<ul>
  <li class="doctor-item-option1 function-option2 doctor-item">doctor-item-option1 function-option2</li>
  <li class="doctor-item-option1 function-option1 doctor-item">doctor-item-option1 function-option1</li>
  <li class="doctor-item-option2 function-option2 doctor-item">doctor-item-option2 function-option2</li>
  <li class="doctor-item-option2 function-option1 doctor-item">doctor-item-option2 function-option1</li>
</ul>
```